# How to assign a value to object property via anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, eval

Let's say I have a function that takes parameters.

In this case I am using [matchHeight](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height), but my question is general.

I set all the options in a variable like this.

```
var options = {
    byRow:    true,
    property: 'height',
    remove:   true,
};
```

And then pass it to the function:

```
$('.some_class').matchHeight(options);
```

Now, I would like to be able to evaluate the 'remove' property dynamically using a function. My guess was using something like this:

```
var options = {
    byRow:    true,
    property: 'height',
    // remove:   true,
    remove: function(){ return true; }
};
```

But, it doesn’t work. What's the correct way to do this?
UPDATE: to be more clear. matchHeight takes remove as a [boolean property](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height#usage), not as a function.

My primary object is to 'emulate' a boolean value such as `remove: true` using a function.

Comment: What do you mean *doesn't work*? That object is roughly correct. It depends how it's consumed in `matchHeight` though and you haven't shown this code. If that's not your code, you can't swap a boolean for a funciton like that. `options.remove` vs `options.remove()`, they're invoked differently

Comment: `options["remove"]`?

Comment: matchHeight takes remove as [boolean property](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height#usage)

Answer (score 2):

If `options.remove` is a function, then you'll have to actually call it:

```
options.remove()
```

If you want to make this work with just `options.remove`, you'll have to [define the property with a getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
var options = {
    byRow:    true,
    property: 'height'
};

Object.defineProperty(options, 'remove', {
    get: function () { return true; }
});

console.log(options.remove);
```

Comment: Thanks. No, `remove` is a [boolean property](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height#usage)

Unfortunately, your code is not working

Comment: Uhm… define "not working". When you click "run code snippet" above it very much *is* working.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach should work - please see this snippet:

```js
var options = {
    byRow:    true,
    property: 'height',
    // remove:   true,
    remove: function(){ return true; }
};

function myFunc(options) {
  console.log(options.remove())
}

myFunc(options)
```